# How to Process a Comma Delimited string in Batches in Oracle 11g

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a comma delimited string which that exceeds the length of VARCHAR2(32767) in Oracle 11g and PL/SQL.

For example, a sample of my string might look like this:

```
my_field:= ‘ "BULL","ABCD","BEER","TOMM", "BULL1","ABCD1","BEER1","TOMM1", "BULL2","ABCD2","BEER2","TOMM2", "BULL3","ABCD3","BEER3","TOMM3", "BULL4","ABCD4","BEER4","TOMM4", "BULL5","ABCD5","BEER5","TOMM5"’;
```

As I am hitting the `**Oracle error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small**`, what I would like to do is take my_field and process this in batches so that I do not exceed my limit of VARCHAR2(32767) in one.

So basically, grab the length of a string up to a specified length that ends with the “,” (comma) – process. Then from the “,” (comma) onwards, grab the next batch length up to a “,” (comma) and process, until I eventually hit the end of my_field, which doesn’t have a “,” (comma).

```
For example:

Batch 1: "BULL","ABCD","BEER","TOMM",       - process row
Batch 2: "BULL1","ABCD1","BEER1","TOMM1",   - process row
Batch 3: "BULL2","ABCD2","BEER2","TOMM2",   - process row
Batch 4: "BULL3","ABCD3","BEER3","TOMM3",   - process row
Batch 5: "BULL4","ABCD4","BEER4","TOMM4",   - process row
Batch 6: "BULL5","ABCD5","BEER5","TOMM5"    - process row
```

All processing finished.

How can I achieve the above in PL/SQL?

Comment: Have you considered using a CLOB?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as I am using DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE which takes in a VARCHAR2 and cannot change this call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSTR and SUBSTR to break the input string into processable substrings, as in the following:

```
DECLARE
  strCSV      VARCHAR2(32767) := '"BULL","ABCD","BEER","TOMM", "BULL1","ABCD1","BEER1","TOMM1", "BULL2","ABCD2","BEER2","TOMM2", "BULL3","ABCD3","BEER3","TOMM3", "BULL4","ABCD4","BEER4","TOMM4", "BULL5","ABCD5","BEER5","TOMM5"';
  strRow_csv  VARCHAR2(32767);
  nStart_pos  NUMBER := 1;
  nEnd_pos    NUMBER;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    nEnd_pos := INSTR(strCSV, ',', nStart_pos, 4);

    strRow_csv := RTRIM(TRIM(SUBSTR(strCSV, nStart_pos, CASE
                                                          WHEN nEnd_pos > 0 THEN
                                                            nEnd_pos
                                                          ELSE
                                                            LENGTH(strCSV)
                                                        END - nStart_pos+1)), ',');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('strRow_csv=''' || strRow_csv || '''');

    IF nEnd_pos = 0 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;

    nStart_pos := nEnd_pos + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you have concerns about commas appearing inside the double-quoted values you may wish to consider using REGEXP_INSTR.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using regular expressions:

```
select word from 
(with t as (select '"aaaa",   "bbbb"   ,    "cccc","dddd eeee", "ffff aaaa"' as txt from dual)
select DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR (txt, '("[^"]+")|^([:space:]*)', 1, level) as word
from t
connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(txt,'("[^"]+")|^([:space:])*'))+1)
where word is not null
```